# If a and b are scalars such that $a\mathbf u+b\mathbf v = 0$ then are $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are parallel vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $a$ and $b$ are scalars such that $a\mathbf u+b\mathbf v = 0$, then $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are parallel vectors.

The answer is false, but I don't know why?

Comment: Hint: What if a and b are both zero?

Comment: thank you so much i swear to dog i was so confuse until u came to my rescue.  i owe u my life.